# Using [JsonExtensionData] with standard ASP.NET Core json configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm trying to map additional fields of Json section to JsonExtensionData property of model class, but it always `null`.

```
var jsonConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(_env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile(_configFilename)
            .Build();
SampleClass sample = jsonConfiguration.Get<SampleClass>();
if (sample.AdditionalData == null) {
 //this is `true`, but why?
```

Class

```
public class SampleClass
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> AdditionalData { get; set; }
}
```

Config sample

```
{
"a" : "val1",
"b" : "val2",
"c" : {
  "r" : "12d",
  "x" : 2
}
```

How to make it map config values to `JToken`'s?

Answer (score 0):

For `Configuration`, it did not provide `JsonExtensionData`.

You could implement your own conversation.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"appsettings.json json path");
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var r = jObject.GetValue("SampleClass");
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SampleClass>(r.ToString());
```

Comment: yeah, I decided to use this way. but I can't get then, what deserializer is used by `ConfigurationBuilder`, may be if I could switch it to use json.net serializer, it would work.